# Neo4j Cypher query null or IN

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a following cypher query:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId}  
RETURN ru, u, childD 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

`Decision` entity can belong to 0..N `Tenant` objects

```
@NodeEntity
public class Decision {
    private final static String BELONGS_TO = "BELONGS_TO";

    @Relationship(type = BELONGS_TO, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Tenant> tenants = new HashSet<>();

....

}
```

I need to extend the Cypher query above in order to return all `childD` where `parentD` and `childD` not belong to any of `Tenant` or belong to `Tenant` with IDs provided in `{tenantIds}` set. Please help me with this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cypher is very expressive language, just follow your textual requirements...

```
MATCH (t:Tenant) WHERE ID(t) in {tenantIds}
WITH COLLECT(t) as tenants
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE 
id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
AND
  // not belong to any of Tenant or belong to Tenant
  (not (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) OR  any(t in tenants WHERE (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t)))
AND
  // not belong to any of Tenant or belong to Tenant 
  (not (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant)  OR  any(t in tenants WHERE (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t)))
RETURN ru, u, childD 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `optional match` to collect and test `tenants`:

```
MATCH (parentD) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId}
  OPTIONAL MATCH (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(T:Tenant) 
           WHERE NOT id(T) IN {tenantIds}
WITH parentD, collect(T) AS TC 
     WHERE size(TC) <= 0
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
  OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(T:Tenant)
           WHERE NOT id(T) IN {tenantIds}
WITH childD, ru, u, collect(T) AS TC
     WHERE size(TC) <= 0
RETURN ru, u, childD 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```