# Neo4j Cypher boolean condition and IN

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In continue to my previous question [Neo4j Cypher query null or IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780255/neo4j-cypher-query-null-or-in) I have added `isPublic` property to `Tenant` node.

Right now I need to extend the query kindly created by [frant.hartm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951609/frant-hartm) with additional check for `parentD` and `childD` tenants for `isPublic` condition.

I have extended my statements to the following:

```
t.isPublic OR t in tenants WHERE (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t)
```

but it fails with a following exception:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Invalid input 'W': expected whitespace, comment, '{', node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ')' (line 1, column 254 (offset: 253))
"MATCH (t:Tenant) WHERE ID(t) in {tenantIds} WITH COLLECT(t) as tenants MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} AND (not(parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) OR any(t.isPublic OR t in tenants WHERE (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t))) AND (not (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) OR any(t.isPublic OR t in tenants WHERE (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t)))  RETURN ru, u, childD ORDER BY childD.createDate ASC SKIP 0 LIMIT 100"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ^
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.executeRequest(EmbeddedRequest.java:175)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.execute(EmbeddedRequest.java:66)
```

The full query right now looks like:

```
MATCH (t:Tenant) WHERE ID(t) in {tenantIds} 
WITH COLLECT(t) as tenants 
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE 
id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
AND
 (not(parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) OR any(t.isPublic OR t in tenants WHERE (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t))) 
AND
 (not (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) OR any(t.isPublic OR t in tenants WHERE (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t)))  
RETURN ru, u, childD 
ORDER BY childD.createDate ASC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

How to fix this query in order to support `t.isPublic` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for any operator is as follows:

```
any(variable IN list WHERE predicate)
```

See: 
https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicates/#functions-any

You have put `t.isPublic` into a wrong place, t is not defined in that context and you need to put it after the inner WHERE clause:

```
any(t in tenants WHERE t.isPublic OR (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In this case query works without exceptions but looks like `t.isPublic` at this place doesn't have sense because finally we check `t` in `tennats`.. but `tenants` may not contain the `Tenant` where `t.isPublic == true`.. Should I add the third `OR` statement dedicated only for `t.isPublic` condition instead ?

Comment: Previously I had 2 conditions - for decision that not belong to any tenants, for decisions that belong to tenants in {tenantIds}.. and right now I have to add the third condition for decisions that belong to tenant with isPublic == true. Right now I don't know how to write this boolean statement for additional OR statement